# Underscore with Foundation Theme Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation

Am a little confused when I was downloading the Underscores theme from GitHub at 
https://github.com/ykhan8/Underscores-Theme-w--Foundation-5. From reading the documentation I don't understand the following documentation within the **README.md** file :

Use a find and replace to change `foundation5_s` to the name of your theme in all the template files.

What is the main reason of using the `@package foundation5_S`

I have checked over the internet but still not sure on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all required. It's primarily for [documentation purposes](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.package.pkg.html):

> Packages are used to help you logically group related elements. You write classes to group related functions and data together, and phpDocumentor represents the contents of files (functions, defines, and includes) as "Procedural Pages." A package is used to group classes and procedural pages together in the same manner that a directory groups related files together.
>
> If found in a page-level DocBlock, packagename specifies the package that all functions, includes, and defines in the php file belong to. If found in a class-level DocBlock, packagename specifies the package that the class belongs to.

Since you're using WordPress, the [WordPress Documentation Standard](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/) includes a bit of additional info:

> **@package**   *packagename*   Specifies package that all functions, includes, and defines in the file belong to. Found in doc block at top of the file. For core (and bundled themes), this is always WordPress.
>
> Third-party plugin and theme authors must not use @package WordPress in their plugins or themes. The @package name for plugins should be the plugin name; for themes, it should be the theme name, spaced with underscores.

Again, it's not required.